# React axios: How to wait data before continuing code

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous, async-await, axios

So I have to call an API to get a token and then use the response to call another API for logging into an app.

With this same code render() is asking for a ';' after it and the console.log is returning the message before the token is returned...

Here is my code:

```
APITOKEN.js:
import axios from 'axios';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

apitoken =  async () =>{
    this.isLoading = true;
try {
    await axios.post('http://192.168.100.60:94/jderest/tokenrequest', {
        username: 'JDE',
        password: 'JDE'
      })
          .then(response => {
           console.log('returned data from api'+response.data.userInfo.token);
            this.userdetails = response.data.userInfo.token;
            this.isLoading = false;
           })
           .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.error = error
            })
 } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR', e);
           this.isLoading = false;
        };
    };
   export default apitoken;   

Login.js

const handleLogin = (credentials,setSubmitting) =>{
    handleMessage(null);

    this.apitoken();
     apitoken =  async () =>{
            await this.props.Apitoken.apitoken();
   } 
    render () {
       const { isLoading, userDetails, error } = this.props.Apitoken
            return (<View>
            {(!!isLoading)?<Text>{userDetails}</Text>:<Text>Loading</Text>}
            </View>)
    };
    console.log('jul222222222');
};
```

Comment: You don't use async/await with then. Remove async await keywords.

Comment: In Login.js I am calling the APITOKEN.js. I have added a log to check if the return comes before with the token or the log would show without waiting the return of the function.